# Intermittent Wiper Wiring Nomenclature

Tags: wiring, wiring-diagram

[image: Auto Wiper and headlight module with intermittent Wiper module schematic for my '64 Chevy restomod.]!
I have drawn up a schematic using instructions and schematics from my car and components I am installing.
My question is in regards to the gray wire at the left side pin 6 of the Rain & Light Sensor Control Module KC-R608.
The instructions say to connect it to "Common Wiper for low and high Speed" " Positive trigger voltage motor. +12vdc."
I have run a jumper from the orange wire from the Wiper switch going into the intermittent Wiper module. Is this correct, or do I just connect the gray wire to 12v ACC wire?

Comment: When, well before, you start testing this fit an extra in-line fuse in the supply feed...

Comment: Also, if you can provide the manufacturer data, or even better, a link to the exact item, I'd be able to give a valid answer. I haven't found anything useful searching just with the data provided thus far.

Answer (score 1):

You should connect the orange wire from the common of the wiper switch to pin 4 on the right side of the 'detroit speed wiper switch connector'. What could be corresponding pin on the left side of that connector (it's not exactly clear just from the drawing) goes to a connector on the 'intermittent power module' according to your drawing. You should be careful if you're jumping or bypassing the 'switch connector' on your own. The same pin from the connector of the 'intermittent power module' is connected to the gray or rather white wire which connects it to pin 6 of the KC-R608 control module. That's the path for the common wire of the wiper speed switch? According to the drawing this common is also connected to the ground or schasis of the car. So definitely don't connect it to any 12V supply or if you're lucky you may only have to replace a fuse.